# Flutter Integration Test Screenshots: convertFlutterSurfaceToImage() not working

Tags: flutter

I am trying to take screenshots in my flutter integration test, but I am getting the below error when `convertFlutterSurfaceToImage()` method is called for `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding` on an Android Emulator. I've looked on the internet for solutions, but couldn't find anything. Also tried different emulators, played around with flutter drive and such, nothing worked.

What is causing the error and is there a fix for it? Thank you.

Here's the method that I am using for the screenshots:

```
takeScreenshot(screenshotName, WidgetTester tester,
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding) async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  }
  await binding.takeScreenshot(screenshotName);
}
```

Error:

```
PlatformException(error, android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView, null, java.lang.ClassCastException:
android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView
    at
dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.FlutterDeviceScreenshot.getFlutterView(FlutterDeviceScreenshot.java:55)
    at
dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.FlutterDeviceScreenshot.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage(FlutterDeviceScreenshot.java:91)
    at
dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.IntegrationTestPlugin.onMethodCall(IntegrationTestPlugin.java:88)
    at
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
    at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
```

**Update 1:**

I noticed that the Android MainActivity is extending FlutterFragmentActivity. So I switched it to FlutterActivity.

So now the `convertFlutterSurfaceToImage()` goes through, but `takeScreenshot()` method gets stuck.